# Remove user's account from Parse

Tags: java, android, authentication, parse-platform, logout

I have this method that runs when a user wants to delete his Parse account:

```
public void onFinish() {
    btnAbortDeletion.setClickable(false);
    System.out.println("Deletion confirmed.");
    final ParseUser userSingout = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    userSingout.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
             if(e == null) {
                 userSingout.logOut();
                 intentLoginPageDeletedAccount();
             } else {
                 Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Something went wrong. Please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .setAction("Action", null).show();
                 dialogDeleteAccout.dismiss();
             }
         }
     });
}
```

This code will work and delete the current logged user from `"User"` on Parse, but the user's session will still be there, despite the `userSingout.logOut();`.

If I try to logout the user first, and then delete his row, it will log him out but not delete him. I've also tried using `userSingout.getObjectId()` to use `userSingout.logOut()` first and then get a query and delete him but it doesn't work either (due some Parse security thing)

Comment: are you using parse-server or parse.com?

Comment: maybe use the CloudCode to delete the user and session (thats the way I do it)